# Were Mermaid passengers shipwrecked by 5 different vessels before being successfully rescued?

Tags: history

In a [post](http://blog.dotcommerce.ro/2011/04/you-think-you-had-bad-luck-think-again.html) by dotcommerce.ro called *You think you had bad luck ? Think again!* this story was mentioned:

> It’s either a case of the worst luck in history or the best:
>
> In 1829, a ship called The Mermaid was four days away from her destination of Sydney, Australia, when a massive storm struck and drove the ship into a reef. All twenty-two people on board survived and were able to swim to safety.
>
> Three days later, the Swiftsure rescued them.
>
> Five days later, the Swiftsure sank.
>
> Victims from both ships were rescued by the schooner Governor Ready.
>
> Three hours later, the Governor Ready caught fire.
>
> The Comet pulled everyone from lifeboats and brought them aboard.
>
> Five days later, the Comet sank. (The crew went for help in the longboat, leaving the passengers floating in the water.)
>
> Eighteen hours later, the mail boat Jupiter pulled everyone out of the ocean.
>
> In under twelve hours, the Jupiter sank.
>
> Everyone was rescued by the passenger vessel The City of Leeds.
>
> Four days later, The City of Leeds docked in Sydney, Australia.
>
> The bad luck was that five ships were lost—the good luck was that not a single person died.

This tale is copied elsewhere on the web, but it's never backed up by references.

As far as I'm concerned, it isn't true. [Wrecksite.eu](http://www.wrecksite.eu/wreck-search.aspx?&se=NsmKW1NwBo8mw/vM95+aWQ==) has a record of a ship called the *Mermaid* that sank in 1829, but it's a European site and *Mermaid* is a common ship name (as evidenced by the other results), so its bearing on the disaster is doubtful.

Wikipedia's convenient [list of shipwrecks in 1829](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shipwrecks_in_1829) mentions *Swiftsure*, *Governor Ready*, *Comet*, and *Jupiter*, but they wrecked so far apart as to be implausible for the tale.

Comment: This story is also featured in the ad section of the [Apr 1910 Popular Mechanics](https://books.google.com/books?id=-90DAAAAMBAJ&pg=RA1-PA125&lpg=RA1-PA125&dq=mermaid+swiftsure+governor+comet+jupiter&source=bl&ots=hr9nMnFajl&sig=sH-BQztm_8zJdEyCvpvYlOxXoVY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6_UrVf2ACoiigwSjiYHwAg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=mermaid%20swiftsure%20governor%20comet%20jupiter&f=false) (attributed to *Nautical Gazette*, but I couldn't find the original source). The times between mishaps are a bit different from the OP's version, but this is an old, notable story for sure.

Comment: @Geobits We've gone from 186 years removed to 81. That's still a lifetime away.

Comment: Sure, just giving an example of the claim from another era. It could still be an old fisherman's tale. Maybe somebody else will have luck finding a better source with that citation.

Comment: @georgechalhoub Despite the initial vowel letter, it's the initial consonantal sound (/j/) that matters.

Comment: Oops. I changed the title to "passengers" without considering that there might have only been crew on board. Is there a better term?

Comment: Quoting Australian Shipwrecks: 1622-1850 at page 87: "...both crews were rescued by the Resource which landed them at Port Raffles...statement that crews of the Mermaid and Swiftsure were taken aboard the Governor Ready and after the latter's wreck all three crews were wrecked in the Comet and finally, along with the Comet's crew, in the Jupiter, is ridiculous"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Dr. Thomas Braidwood Wilson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Braidwood_Wilson) of the Royal Geographical Society kept a daily log published in 1835 as [Narrative of a Voyage Round the World; Comprehending an Account of the Wreck of the Ship Governor Ready in Torres Straits](https://books.google.com/books?id=YcwNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA83&dq=%22Swiftsure%22+%22governor+ready%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bf0rVfnGAfWLsQS80oD4Cg&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=snippet&q=mermaid&f=false), which together with other first-hand accounts prove that the story in the OP is largely false:

The *Mermaid* wrecked 13 June 1829.  "The crew took to the whale-boat, and, after three days, were picked up by the schooner Admiral Gifford, and shortly afterwards sent on board the Swiftsure; which ship was, on July 5th, wrecked off Cape Sidmouth" (quoting from page 83).

The *Mermaid* and *Swiftsure* crews were brought to land at Raffles Bay by the **Resource** 22 July 1829.

The *Amity* was in port at Raffles Bay when the *Resource* arrived and had been expecting the *Mermaid*, but the *Resource* came instead.

A detailed first-hand account of the wreck of the *Governor Ready* is also given, but this was an earlier event.

The *Governor Ready* was irreparably damaged at 2:45 PM 18 May 1829 (see page 12).  The crew travels in three of their smaller boats (skiff, jolly-boat, long-boat) until they meet the docked *Amity* on 02 June 1829 (see pages 45-49).  At this point the crew of the *Governor Ready* separates, Captain Young going to Batavia on the long boat, and Dr. Wilson going to Raffles Bay on the *Amity*.  The *Amity* reaches Raffles Bay 2PM 31 June 1829 (see page 71).

Given that the author Dr. Wilson was actually aboard the *Governor Ready* when the wreck occurred, and personally met with the master of the *Mermaid* when the *Mermaid* crew arrived on the *Resource*, the portion of the story in the question concerning the *Governor Ready* is inaccurate.

As for the *Comet*, as reported in [19 October 1829 London Times](http://www.newspapers.com/newspage/32876206/), explaining that the second officer and a seaman of the Comet arrived in Cowes on 17 October (on the *Maria* having departed Batavia 30 June) to account for the wreck of the Comet to her owners and:

> The 2nd officer stated that the Comet sailed from Sydney for Batavia on the 13th of April, made Torres Strait on the 5th of May. On the 6th at 4 a. m., thick weather, struck on a reef ... and was a complete wreck, the surf running so high that no boat could be put out obliged the crew to remain three days exposed ...subsisting on raw beef; at the expiration of that time succeeded ...steered north for Murray's Island, at 4PM saw it, and a brig at anchor; at 6 got on board, which proved to be the Fairfield, of Aberdeen, Captain Both, who recieved us politely, and attended to our immediate wants

As for the *Jupiter*, in the same article the 2nd officer continues:

> on the 14th of May the Fairfield spoke the ship Jupiter...which had struck on Boot reef...she was proceeding to Calcutta for repairs

The 2nd officer further states:

> Prior to the Maria's leaving Batavia, Captain Young, formerly of the ship Governor Reading [sic], of London, had arrived there with part of his crew, that ship having been unfortunately wrecked on a shoal in the vicinity of Murray's Island

So the order of events is:

**6 May 1829**: *Comet* wrecks (crew rescued by *Fairfield*)

**14 May 1829**: *Jupiter* is proceeding to Calcutta for repairs

**18 May 1829**: *Governor Ready* wrecks (crew eventually reaches the *Amity* 02 June)

**13 June 1829**: *Mermaid* wrecks (crew eventually rescued by the *Admiral Gifford*, transferred to *Swiftsure*)

**5 July 1829**: *Swiftsure* wrecks (crew rescued by *Resource*)

**22 July 1829**: *Resource* brings crews of *Mermaid* and *Swiftsure* to port at Raffles Bay where the *Amity* is expecting the *Mermaid*.

From this timeline is can be seen that the story in the OP is very inaccurate.

That the *Mermaid* and *Swiftsure* crews were transferred to the *Resource* rather than the *Governor Ready* is further corroborated by  a letter from Samuel Nolbrow, the captain of the *Mermaid* published in the [30 October 1829 Colonial Times article](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/8644632), which further confirms:

*Governor Ready* wrecked 3PM on 18 May 1829.

*Mermaid* was abandoned 8PM 13 June 1829

*Swiftsure* was lost 4 July 1829 and crew was rescued by *Resource*.

Date of *Comet* wreck is not stated, but article says crew was rescued by the *Fairfield*.

As further confirmation see the first hand account of [Collet Barker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collet_Barker), commander of the Raffles Bay settlement publishied as [Commandant of Solitude: The Journals of Captain Collet Barker, 1828-1831](https://books.google.com/books?ei=Tm8tVcHOM7eOsQTi8YGQDw&id=NYugAAAAMAAJ&dq=swiftsure%20mermaid%20resource&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=resource), which explains that Dr. Wilson first wrecked on the *Governor Reidy* [sic], and came to Raffles Bay on the *Amity*.  Then on 22 July the *Resource* arrived with the crews of the *Mermaid* and *Swiftsure*.

Additionally, published in [Historical Records of Australia: Despatches and papers relating to the settlement of the states](https://books.google.com/books?id=pSpAAQAAMAAJ&q=swiftsure%20resource%20nolbrow&dq=swiftsure%20resource%20nolbrow&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V61YVctZyeywBdeIgKgG&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA), Australia Parliament Joint Library Committee, at page 835, is a 22 August 1829 letter from Collet Barker:

> ...loss of the Mermaid, which I regret to state was wrecked in Torres Strait on the 13 June.  Her crew were all saved and were brought here by the Resource, the Master of which wished to have left them in consequence of being short of provisions and having with him the crew of another wrecked vessel, the Swiftsure. He consented however to take them except the Master, Mr. Nolbrow, on my supplying them with thirty two days provisions. I ordered Mr. Nolbrow on board the Amity and receiving an urgent request from Mr. Hastings,
>   Chief Mate, and Thos. Long, Seaman, to be allowed to go to Sydney, I also ordered them a passage in the same vessel

Also, the Jupiter arrived in Calcutta 5 July 1829, as recorded at [page 32 of The Asiatic Journal and Monthly Register for British and Foreign India, China and Australasia, vol. 1, January-April 1830](https://books.google.com/books?id=rCkoAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Asiatic%20Journal%201830&hl=en&sa=X&ei=No1bVcXwKqLasASY0YGwCg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=jupiter&f=false) and was not unrepairable but instead was in service in the Persian Gulf by May of 1830 ([Calcutta Magazine and Monthly Register, October 1830, page 87](https://books.google.com/books?id=9xoYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA87&dq=jupiter%20persian%20weldy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1O9dVfeOIpf_sATjhIGQAg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=jupiter%20persian%20weldy&f=false)).

Also in the above volume of Asiatic Journal:

> The Swiftsure, Johnson, of London, from New South Wales, was wrecked 4th July Torres Straits. The crew and passengers were saved by the Resource, Smith, and had arrived at the Mauritius 17th Aug., with part of the cargo, stores &c.

So in summary the first hand accounts of Dr. Wilson, captain Nolbrow, and Collet Barker all show that the only true parts of the story are that the *Mermaid* wrecked, the crew was rescued by the *Swiftsure* which also wrecked and both crews were rescued.  It is also true that the *Governor Ready* and *Comet* wrecked in the same time period, but these were earlier events, and the *Mermaid* crew was not rescued by these ships.

The inaccurate tale in the OP originates from a [26 November 1829 story](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/2193945) in the Sydney Gazette, which could easily be mistaken for the truth, but for the existence of *Mermaid* Captain Nolbrow's 30 October 1829 letter published in the Colonial Times, the day-by-day accounts of Dr. Wilson and Collet Barker, and the account of 2nd officer of the *Comet* in the 19 October 1829 London Times.

The evidence agrees with the conclusion of maritime historian [Charles Bateson](http://adb.anu.edu.au/biography/bateson-charles-henry-9452), as stated in his book [Australian Shipwrecks: 1622-1850](https://books.google.com/books?id=U9E3AQAAIAAJ&q=%22Australian%20Shipwrecks:%201622-1850%22%20ridiculous&dq=%22Australian%20Shipwrecks:%201622-1850%22%20ridiculous&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xd4vVZiFLMTjsAS8o4GgAQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA) at page 87:

> ...both crews were rescued by the Resource which landed them at Port Raffles...statement that crews of the Mermaid and Swiftsure were taken aboard the Governor Ready and after the latter's wreck all three crews were wrecked in the Comet and finally, along with the Comet's crew, in the Jupiter, is ridiculous

Comment: I have added a contemporary source for the ANMM version to my answer. However, your researched version is pretty convincing too. I actually didn't pay attention to the dates when I was initially looking things up. But [this Trove link](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/36867550) (which I've also used in my answer oblivious to the sequence mismatch) from Nov, 1829, notes the involvement of the Resource in the rescue of the Swiftsure. Rather than amending mine, I'd prefer to see you expanding yours and have both answers coexist.

Comment: Other (earlier) articles which might also be of use: [1](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/36867550), [2](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/8644632), [3](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/84773320), [4](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/2193748).

Comment: @coleopterist Great finds!  I'll work some of those into the answer.  Seems like the 26 November 1829 in the Sydney Gazette started the story, but that the article is inaccurate.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't adding the expert opinion of Charles Bateson?

Comment: @coleopterist I could, but I'm trying to use primary sources

Comment: @coleopterist ok, I added

Comment: You'll want to mention Bateson's credentials, link to the book/source of the quote, etc. Is this a Google Books snippet? Reliable secondary sources are, IMO, better when primary sources are being questioned (as is the case here).

Comment: @coleopterist ok, I linked to his wikipedia article and book, and gave the page number of the quoted passage

Comment: Bateson appears to be rebutting the story as told by [Sir John Henniker Heaton](http://library.si.edu/digital-library/book/lifelettersofsi00port) (p.159).

Comment: @coleopterist yes, but from his 1879 "Australian Dictionary of Dates and Men of the Time: Containing the History of Australasia from 1542 to May, 1879" at page 83, which I originally had in my answer, but deleted because it was clear the 26 November 1829 source was more primary https://books.google.com/books?id=NwYuAAAAYAAJ&dq=history+of+australia+swiftsure+mermaid+jupiter&q=swiftsure#v=snippet&q=swiftsure&f=false

Comment: This is now one of the most self-edited answers on the site. I'm hoping you are getting close to finishing polishing your answer!

Comment: @Oddthinking I think I'm getting close now, though the 1838 book "Shipwreck of the Sterling Castle" describes how Captain Fraser (the captian of the Comet) latter wrecked the Sterling Castle with his wife Eliza aboard and was then murdered.  The book contains an interesting poem Fraser wrote as the Comet was wrecked on the reef.

Answer (score 59):

[image: HMS Mermaid]

<sup><sub>The HMS Mermaid</sub></sup>

**The account is largely true.**

The Royal Navy's [HMS Mermaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Mermaid_(1817)) (after a distinguished career) did [sink](https://dmzapp17p.ris.environment.gov.au/shipwreck/public/wreck/wreck.do?key=2868) in [1829](https://anmm.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/a-model-tale/). The [Australian National Maritime Museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_National_Maritime_Museum) salvaged the wreck in 2009 and wrote about the ship (and the subsequent misfortune) in its quarterly magazine, [Signals](http://www.anmm.gov.au/learn/library-and-research/signals-magazine).

Quoting from page 17 of the [March-April-May issue](http://issuu.com/anmmuseum/docs/signals_86):

> That afternoon at 1730, during another attempt to drive the vessel over the reef, Mermaid rolled over onto her beam ends and within a few minutes the hull was breeched. At 2000 hours the crew abandoned ship and took to the boats.
>
> On 24 June 1829, **after 11 days** in the open boats, the crew were rescued by the small schooner **Admiral Gifford**. On account of overcrowding, the survivors were transferred to the much larger wooden brig **Swiftsure** on 3 July – and on board this vessel they were promptly wrecked again off Cape Sidmouth, just 18 hours later! According to *The Sydney Gazette* of 26 November 1829, the crew of the Mermaid was to endure **two further shipwrecks** (on **Governor Ready** and **Comet**) before being landed at Port Raffles. Here they embarked on the government brig **Amity** which sailed westwards for King George Sound, before finally returning some of the crew to Sydney five months later.

[An interview with the museum's curator](http://www.sportdiver.com/keywords/hm-schooner-mermaid/wreck-finds-hm-schooner-mermaid) reiterates this account.

So, there's no mention in this write-up of the mail boat, *Jupiter* or the *City of Leeds*. But an *Admiral Gifford* is mentioned. Some other minor details are also in conflict. However, it is true that at least four of the ships involved were wrecked.

A different source, a copy of [The Australian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Australian_(1824_newspaper)) from [25 November, 1829](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/36867550) does note that a ship named *Jupiter* did crash into reefs off Cairncross Island and suffer serious damage. It also notes the wrecks of the *Mermaid*, *Comet*, and *Swiftsure*. The *Admiral Gifford* also eventually had rudder problems :o

[The Australian National Shipwreck Database](http://www.environment.gov.au/topics/heritage/historic-shipwrecks/australian-national-shipwreck-database) does not include any vessels named Jupiter either. The four wrecks mentioned in the National Maritime Museum account do have entries along with maps ([Mermaid](https://dmzapp17p.ris.environment.gov.au/shipwreck/public/wreck/wreck.do?key=2868), [Swiftsure](https://dmzapp17p.ris.environment.gov.au/shipwreck/public/wreck/wreck.do?key=3170), [Governor Ready](https://dmzapp17p.ris.environment.gov.au/shipwreck/public/wreck/wreck.do?key=2565), [Comet](https://dmzapp17p.ris.environment.gov.au/shipwreck/public/wreck/wreck.do?key=2338)) pinpointing their wrecks (which are in relative proximity to each other).

[image: Governor Ready sinking]

<sup><sub>The crew abandon a sinking *Governor Ready*</sub></sup>

---

**Update:**

The ANMM's article references a [26 November 1829 article](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/2193945) in the [Sydney Gazette (and New South Wales Advertiser)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydney_Gazette) (an "official publication of the government of New South Wales") which reads as follows:

> Captain Nolbrow, who is well known here as an old commander, trading to our shores, arrived by the Calista. He has been singularly unfortunate, more so than we ever remember to have heard of in the instance of any surviving shipwrecked mariner. He sailed from Sydney in the Mermaid, Colonial Government cutter, for Port Raffles, which settlement, our readers are aware, the Government of the sister Colony has, by order from home, caused to be evacuated. **On entering Torres' Straits, the Mermaid got a-shore and was lost.** All on board saved, upon a rock. In **three days** the ship **Swiftsure**, which sailed from this port, hove in sight, and took on board Captain Nolbrow and his crew. In three days she got on shore and was wrecked, all on board saved. In a day or two the **Governor Ready**, also from this port, passing within sight, took the shipwrecked people onboard, and was in three days himself wrecked, but all the people saved. The ship **Comet**, also from this port, soon after took the whole of the collected crews of the lost ships on board, and was herself wrecked also in a day or two, but all the people saved. At last the ship **Jupiter**, also from this port, came in sight and taking all on board steered for Port Raffles, at the entrance of which harbour she got on shore and received so much damage that she may be said to half wrecked. There however, Captain Nolbrow found the Government brig **Amity** in which he embarked, and strange to say this vessel also was, as we have stated in the former part of this article, nearly wrecked in Gage's Roads.

This piece published only a few months after the event does conform just about completely with the story as related in the OP. The *Jupiter* is stated to have "half-wrecked" and even the *Amity*, "nearly wrecked".

Comment: The book I have says that *Jupiter* landed them at Port Raffles. *Jupiter* struck the harbour, and didn't sink, but was subsequently deemed irreparable.

Comment: @ChrisW Which book is this?

Comment: *The Ultimate Book of Heroic Failures* by Stephen Pile.

Comment: From **The Least Successful Boat Rescue** on page 125: "Seven days later the *Comet* sank in a sudden storm and the passengers, now accompanied by four separate crews, were rescued by the *Jupiter*. In all four shipwrecks not a single life was lost, but the *Jupiter* struck the harbour at Port Raffles and was later scuttled when found to be beyond repair."

Comment: 1730 and 1829?  99 years seems quite distant...

Comment: @Izkata "1730" is presumably a time-of-day (not a year), i.e. "17:30", i.e. "5:30 PM".

Comment: @ChrisW Ah yes, I was think it might be a bizarre typo.  That makes sense, though

Comment: @coleopterist The "Governor Ready" sank 18 May 1929, so there is no way it could have rescued the Merrmaid and Swiftsure crews.

Comment: @DavePhD: Where are you getting that date? Everything I've found, e.g. [here](http://adb.anu.edu.au/biography/wilson-thomas-braidwood-2806) and [here](http://www.jenwilletts.com/convict_ship_governor_ready_1829.htm) as well as the articles and [shipwreck database](https://dmzapp17p.ris.environment.gov.au/shipwreck/public/wreck/wreck.do?key=2565) given in the answer, says it sunk 100 years earlier than that, in 1829.

Comment: @user2357112 In his own answer he wrote, "2:45 PM 18 May 1829", so "1929" is a typo in this comment, and when he wrote "no way" that's because of the month, i.e. May, given that *Mermaid* and *Swiftsure* wrecked in June and July.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, 1829.  2:45 PM 18 May 1829

Comment: @coleopterist the Australian National Shipwreck Database link in your answer says (if you click on wreck event) "The 'Governor Ready' left Hobart on the 2nd of April 1829 bound for Batavia (Jakarta), via Sydney. At 3:00pm on the 18th of May the vessel struck a small detached coral patch in the Torres Strait (Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser 12/12/1829:2) midway between Murray's and Half-way Islands (Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser 03/11/1829:2). (continues below)

Comment: (continued from above) The rock penetrated the vessel's bottom and the 'Governor Ready' immediately filled with water (Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser 12/12/1829:2). The captain and crew abandoned the vessel and made for Timor, where they arrived after 14 days at sea (Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser 03/11/1829:2).

Comment: Quoting Australian Shipwrecks: 1622-1850 by Charles Bateson at page 87: "...both crews were rescued by the Resource which landed them at Port Raffles...statement that crews of the Mermaid and Swiftsure were taken aboard the Governor Ready and after the latter's wreck all three crews were wrecked in the Comet and finally, along with the Comet's crew, in the Jupiter, is ridiculous"

Comment: The Sydney Gazette says that the 26 November 1829 article is a reprinting of an article from another newspaper, saying at the beginning of the article "From the Tasmanian".

Comment: The museum currator does not include the Comet or Jupiter in his version.  He says the Amity rescued the crews of the Mermaid, Swiftsure and Governor Ready, which is closer to the truth, but still wrong.

Answer (score -4):

Regarding these various shipwrecks, there are a number of very early reports within merely the time needed for the various eyewitnesses to reach  the towns where these reports originated.  There, nevertheless, does appear to be discrepancies.

The report of Nov. 26, 1829 in the SIDNEY GAZETTE seems to contradict the report in a previous edition .  Is this a mistaken article or is it a different report of the event by a different witness?

We cannot say that it is the result of a gradual embellishment over time, nor can we say that it is story surfacing at a much later time.  It is a version of the event that exists close to the beginning side by side with the other.  Moreover, it is a version that does not seem to have been challenged in later editions of the newspaper. In fact it is the version that largely survived in Australian history (for example: IN THE EARLY DAYS; J.J. Knight, Brisbane, 1895).

History is made up not only of the official reports of the big people: Governors, Captains and officers; it includes as well the testimony of the little people: sailors, passengers and even convicts.   Their input also has a right to be evaluated.

When the same newspaper, in a later edition, publishes a somewhat different account, it usually means that someone reading the prior edition wishes to correct the record, add something else, or present his or her own version of how things happened.

Most here (in this discussion) agree, at least, that after the Mermaid sank June 12/13, they were saved by the Admiral Grifford and then transferred to the Swiftsure, which also became disabled.  The combined crews (along with some of the cargo) were brought by the Resource and let off at Port Raffles where they met up with Dr. Wilson, newly returned from Coupang on the Amity.

From there the Amity took Captain Nolbrow and "some of the crew" westward to Swan River on the west side of Australia, and then, aboard the Calista, eastward along the south side of Australia,  to Albany and King George Sound, then on to Hobart (Tasmania) where Captain Nolbrow leaves a report of these events published by the local newspaper.  Then they proceeded northward  along the east side of Australia to Sidney. Some ships there, like the Amity encountered various difficulties and delays at Swan River and thus Nolbrow continues on the Calista and reportedly other crew as well.

Comment: Please do not make more than one answer to a question. It is much better to edit your existing answer. Please make sure you have read the help pages (under the help menu) to find out how things work here, which are a bit different from a normal forum.

Comment: Please use [chat] to debate this topic. Use the comments for suggestions on how to improve the answer. Do not use the answers or the comments to post your opinions or reasoning.

Comment: The Jupiter's Calcutta repair trip must have been different than the Java repair trip. After the Calcutta repairs some of the Mermaid crew returning to Sidney could have been on the Jupiter as the Australian paper reports. Whether or not the Sidney paper identified correctly the place of the Jupiter accident, they knew that it happened; and if it happened north of Sidney (Cairnscross Island) and then went for repairs further north, how would they know that it happened unless it were carrying passengers to Sidney or passengers to Sidney by the northeast route passed it on their way to Sidney?

Comment: I do not wish off-hand to reject your (DavePhD) chronology of Jupiter's Carinscross accident (April or May), but I would point out, that if Nolbrow knew from his going trip northward, he does not seem to have communicated it at Port Raffles, nor at Hobart, but only later by letter (presumably from Sidney).  Moreover, in that letter, he does not say that the Jupiter "went" to Java (i.e. in April or May), but rather "and gone to Java", as in a recent still happening event.

Comment: @RTCarleton The news about the Jupiter reached Hobart via the Calista as explained in this 10/31 article http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/4212571 in addition to the 10/30 article http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/8644632.  At almost the same time, the news about the Jupiter reached Sydney via the Amity as published 10/30 here http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/36866262

Comment: According to the testimony in London of the officer of the Comet, the grounding of the Jupiter happened at Boot Reef, which is over a hundred miles further northeast than  Cairnscross Island, and further north than the wreck of the Comet (Australian Government's shipwreck web site).  If indeed the Jupiter accident happened (as you maintain) earlier than the 14th of May) and so far from the path of the Mermaid (which did not leave Sidney until the 16th of May), why did Nolbrow say Cairnscross Island?

Comment: @RTCarleton Jupiter arrived in Calcutta 5 July 1829, as recorded at page 32 of The Asiatic Journal and Monthly Register for British and Foreign India, China and Australasia, vol. 1, January-April 1830. I added to my answer.

Comment: One of the main arguments against the OP is the failure of Dr. Wilson to mention the Comet. Dr. Wilson is present in Port Raffles when the Mermaid survivors arrive. Present then, are the Captain and crew of the Mermaid and the Captain and crew of the Swiftsure.  As to the Comet: there is no boat, no Captain and no crew. For all practical purposes it is like an invisible and irrelevant chapter in the Mermaid saga. Dr. Wilson's observations of his visit there are taken up with questions of the abandonment of the settlement (orders for which were delivered by Nolbrow) and stories of the natives.

Comment: DavePhD: The Swiftsure shipwrecked July 4th (Australian gov. site) and they arrived at Port Raffles 22 July.  What happened in the intervening 18 days? The traditional account says that the Swiftsure  was rescued after only 8 hours. There's 17 plus days to account for a journey from Cape Sidmouth to Port Raffles! There is too big a hole in this version. Too big a gap in the story. There would have to be something missing.

Comment: @RTCarleton I don't know how long it took be for the Resource find the Swiftsure after wrecking, how long it took to transfer cargo, etc.  Asiatic Journal says "The Swiftsure, Johnson, of London, from New South Wales, was wrecked 4th July Torres Straits.  The crew and passengers were saved by the Resource, Smith, and had arrived at the Mauritius 17th Aug., with part of the cargo, stores &c."

Comment: A interesting coincidence or discrepancy, or maybe a discrepancy of interest: "The Comet lost on Boots' Reef"  (The Australian Sydney, Wed. 25 Nov. 1829)
"the ship Jupiter...which had struck on Boot reef...she was proceeding to Calcutta for repairs" (2nd officer of Comet).

Comment: @RTCarleton the 26 November 1829 Sydney Gazette article shouldn't be taken as expressing the viewpoint of that newspaper, as the top of the article clearly says that it is taken from an article of a different newspaper, the Tasmanian.  With numerous contridictions of numerous other sources, no weight should be given to this account.  That one second-hand article is the only 1829 source that supports involvement of the Governor Ready, Comet or Jupiter in the rescue of the Mermaid crew.

Comment: @DavePhD I absolutely agree that the Gazette article has to be subjected to a rigourous "fact check" (which you have helped to clarify), but I point out that practically ALL the reports contain SOME problems and inconsistencies, AND many of them do in fact list the same series of ships, without specifying the interconnections.  The Gazette article declares, either somewhat erroneously, completely erroneously, or with some truth, the chronology.